# Countenance, as noun, versus appearance

Tags: meaning

Jane Austen seems to use them as separate things.  Often the appearance of the face may be deduced from context.  I no longer remember which book or what character I was reading when I encountered something like, "He was not handsome, but he had a good countenance."  (Quotes for convenience.  Probably not a direct quote.)
Thanks for guidance on this.

Comment: In its obsolete sense, countenance refers to attitude, bearing or posture.

Comment: Even in its modern sense, there's OED: *Appearance, aspect, look (obs. exc. as transf. from [**countenance=The look or expression of a person's face**]); also, a **show or semblance of anything***. So Austen's usage could simply mean that although he wasn't inherently *handsome*, his mien/appearance was more attractive than it might have been - because he was well-groomed (no straggly beard), friendly-faced (not scowling), or whatever.

Comment: Would you be able to rephrase as a more direct question?

Comment: Josh B, as a question.  In literature in the later 18th and much of the 19th century, what is the difference between "being handsome" and "having a good countenance"?    A little awkward; that's why I used the example and asked for guidance.  The OED quote was very helpful, and added to attitude and bearing makes it quite clear.